# Generate a bunch of tkinter checkbuttons and read the status of all those radio buttons at once

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have a tkinter class which reads some data into a couple of lists. From this now i have created a dictionary for creating checkbuttons.

I'm trying to create those checkbuttons in a new window() with a button to submit and read the stutus of those. I want this data to process.

```
    def get_data(self):
        self.flags = ["one","two","three", "four"]
        self.tests = ["Jack","Queen","King","Ace"]
        self.value = [11,12,13,1]
        self.dict1 = {k:v for k,v in enumerate(self.flags,1)}
    def get_status(self):
        self.selectWindow = Toplevel(root)
        self.selectWindow.title("Select Test Cases")
        Submit_btn = Button(selectWindow, text="Submit", command=read_status )
        for testcase in self.dict1:
            self.dict1[testcase] = Variable()
            l = Checkbutton(self.selectWindow,text=self.dict1[testcase], variable=self.dict1[testcase])
            l.pack()
    def read_status(self):
        pass
```

From here I'm not able go ahead and read the status of checkbuttons and get those are checked. I need this data for further processing on tests(not actual lists given here I have few more).  How to solve? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

`Checkbutton` has a built in `command` function that can solve this problem. Every time you press a button that function is called, and you can print out the values of the buttons (0,1)

```
def get_data(self):
    self.flags = ["one","two","three", "four"]
    self.tests = ["Jack","Queen","King","Ace"]
    self.value = [11,12,13,1]
    self.dict1 = {k:v for k,v in enumerate(self.flags,1)}
def get_status(self):
    self.selectWindow = Toplevel(self)
    self.selectWindow.title("Select Test Cases")
    self.get_data()
    Submit_btn = Button(self.selectWindow, text="Submit", command=read_status ) # This button should be packed
    Submit_btn.pack()
    for testcase in self.dict1:
        self.dict1[testcase] = Variable()
        l = Checkbutton(self.selectWindow,text=self.dict1[testcase], variable=self.dict1[testcase], command=self.read_status) # Note the command
        l.pack()
    self.selectWindow.mainloop()

# Here comes the interesting part

def read_status(self):
    for i,j in self.dict1.iteritems():
        print j.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use `self` and `pack` method:

```
Submit_btn = Button(self.selectWindow, text="Submit", command=self.read_status )
Submit_btn.pack()
```

`Checkbutton`'s states are `(0, 1)` so use `IntVar()` to inspect the state:

```
...
self.dict1[testcase] = IntVar()
...
```

Then use IntVar `get` method:

```
def read_status(self):
    for v in self.dict1:
        print self.dict1[v].get()
```